# Is this pattern to reduce the scope of variables declared within an if statement a good practice?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scope

I saw this pattern recently

```
if(condition) {
    (function() {
        var foo = "bar";
        // do somehing with foo
    })();
}
// no more foo
```

It looks a little bit like a hack, and I was wondering if the usage of this pattern is a good practice?

Comment: No, that's pretty odd imo. The immediately invoked function expression is generally only used for module patterns or to counter weird loop situations.

Comment: Is there something outside of the function that is also used inside the function? Creating a closure like this can indeed be helpful, but it's by no means a standard practice

Comment: Your question needs some context. Why do you need to keep `foo` confined to the conditional?

Comment: You say sole purpose is to contain scope, but you haven't shown any reason to do that. So it seems pointless and inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be useful if you wanted to use a closure to create private variables depending on a condition. You'd want to likely assigned out the return value of the function, but you might use this pattern for something like:

```
 //conditionally check if we want a counting option    
 if(counterIsEnabled){

 //if we do, create a private count object
var counterObject = (function(){
 var count = 0;

 //and make it only accessible via a returned method
 return {
      inc: function(){ count += 1; },
      get: function(){ return count}

  }

})();

}
```

It's essentially just conditionally creating a closure, which is useful if you want private variables and public accessor/setter methods to control exactly how that variable is accessed or changed.

Doing it this way means that no one can directly access the `count` variable without using your pre-defined methods.